# Access 2003 VBA / Sql Update TableA on count condition also in TableA

Tags: sql, vba, count, ms-access-2003

I'm very new to Sql, and having trouble wrapping my brain around the syntax. I have a table PM (with Fields Acct, Amt, Action, Reason), and I need to update a few fields in the table wherever count(Acct)>1, and the Amt is the same. Specifically, based on this select statement:

```
SELECT PM.Acct, PM.Amt
FROM PM
GROUP BY PM.Amt
HAVING (((Count(PM.Acct))>1));
```

That code returns the records I know need to be changed, anyway. Once someone explains it, I'm sure it will be obvious, but I'm stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way, then you are still using your `GROUP BY` for your `Amt`. This was tested in MS Access 2003 and only updates the records in the sub-query:

```
UPDATE PM
SET PM.Amt = newValue
    , (other fields and values)
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT t.Acct, t.Amt
    FROM PM t
    WHERE PM.Acct = t.Acct
    GROUP BY t.Acct, t.Amt
    HAVING Count(t.Acct)>1
)
```

Comment: I get what you're doing, and that helps a ton, but I get an error: You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'Acct' as part of an aggregate function.

Comment: You can add to the subquery GROUP BY, t.Acct.   I edited my answer

Comment: I'm still getting an error, but it's a data type mismatch, and that's all on me. Thank you!

Comment: if this solution works for you, be sure to mark it as the accepted answer via the checkmark on the left.